# Strip off layer from MonadResource

Tags: haskell

I'm playing around with the leveldb bindings.

I'm wondering if it's possible to take a function like

```
MonadResource m => a -> m b
```

And convert it to

```
MonadResource m => m (a -> IO b))
```

Comment: In general this isn't possible because `a` is going from the negative to the positive position (I think). You might get better help if you elaborated on your problem on a little. Which LevelDB function are you looking at with this type? Is this the leveldb-haskell library?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? If you to perform any IO action inside it, use `liftIO`.

Comment: This is the leveldb-haskell library.

Comment: The problem is, there's a data type used extensively in the code base I'm working on, which is essentially a grab bag of IO functions. changing them to be MonadResource functions means a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can definitely be done, but it's dangerous. Let's demonstrate first the how, by extracting the internal state of the `ResourceT`:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal

data Foo = Foo Int
    deriving Show

getFoo :: MonadResource m => Int -> m Foo
getFoo i = fmap snd $ allocate
    (do
        putStrLn $ "allocating Foo with " ++ show i
        return $ Foo i)
    (\(Foo x) -> putStrLn $ "Freeing Foo " ++ show x)

stripLayer :: MonadResource m => (a -> ResourceT IO b) -> m (a -> IO b)
stripLayer f = do
    is <- liftResourceT getInternalState
    return $ \a -> runInternalState (f a) is

main :: IO ()
main = do
    getFoo' <- runResourceT $ stripLayer $ getFoo
    getFoo' 42 >>= print
```

Unfortunately the output from this isn't what we'd hope for:

```
allocating Foo with 42
Foo 42
```

Notice how the "Freeing" line is never called. This is because, by the time we use `getFoo'`, the `runResourceT` call has already exited, which is how we guarantee that all resources are freed. You *can* safely get away with this trick if you're disciplined and make sure everything lives inside the `runResourceT` call, but the type system won't help you. To see what this will look like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
    getFoo' <- stripLayer $ getFoo
    liftIO $ getFoo' 42 >>= print
```